# RDF 3x triplestore is in-memory or disk based

Tags: database, rdf, triplestore

Is RDF-3x triplestore in-memory or disk based?

Comment: Did you actually read their paper which gives a comprehensive description of the system?

Answer (score 2):

The paper that RobV mentions is

> Neumann, Thomas, and Gerhard Weikum. “[RDF-3X: a RISC-style engine for RDF](http://www3.in.tum.de/teaching/ws1112/vwis/exercises/Blatt11/rdf3x.pdf).” Proceedings of the VLDB Endowment 1.1 (2008): 647-659.

If you're familiar with some of the data structures used to implement databases, then the fact that they are using [B+-trees](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B+_tree) would strongly suggest to you that they are using on-disk rather than in memory models.  If you don't have much exposure to those structures, then it might not be so obvious.  A few points in the paper are more direct though (emphasis added):

> Note that both MonetDB and RDF-3X could import the data sets in less than half an hour, and could run the queries in the order of seconds. **Other semantic web approaches usually assume that the RDF data fits into main memory, which is not the case here.** All experiments below therefore only consider RDF-3X, the column-stored-based approach on top of MonetDB, and the PostgreSQL-based triples store.

They also clear the filesystem cache before running their tests.  This would have some effect on loading the query engine, but much more on the performance of filesystem-based databases:

> For evaluating the performance of RDF-3X, we used three
>   large datasets with dierent characteristics and compared
>   the query run-times to other approaches (discussed below).
>   All experiments were conducted on a Dell D620 PC with
>   a 2 Ghz Core 2 Duo processor, 2 GBytes of memory, and
>   running a 64-bit Linux 2.6.24 kernel. **For the cold-cache
>   experiments we used the /proc/sys/vm/drop caches kernel
>   interface to drop all filesystem caches before restarting
>   the various systems under test.** We repeated all queries
>   five times (including the dropping of caches and the system
>   restart) and took the best result to avoid artifacts caused by
>   OS activity. For warm caches we ran the queries five times
>   without dropping caches, again taking the best run-time.

Noting the performance RDF-3X as a result of reading less from disk:

> When comparing the cold-cache times and the warm-cache times,
>   it becomes clear that disk I/O has a large impact on the
>   overall run-times. RDF-3X simply reads less data due to its
>   highly compressed index structures[.]